# 1170: Function does not return a value

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am a bit new to flash and actionscript but i am learning. With this code I am trying to get a message that says `true` when the `value` is between `from` and `to`. When I run this it gives the error in the title. What am I doing wrong?

```
from = Number(txtFra.text);
value = Number(txtTall.text);
to = Number(txtTil.text);
var from:Number;
var value:Number;
var value:Number;

function insideIntervall(from:int, value:int, to:int):Boolean
{
    var bool:Boolean
    if (from<value<to)
    {
        bool = true;
    }
    else
    {
        bool = false;
    }
    if (bool == true)
    {
        trace("True");
    }
    else
    {
        trace("False");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function definition has `):Boolean` at the end, which means there's a contract that says this function will return a true or false value.    Likely what you want to do is just `return bool` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 3):

The error in the title is because your function must explicitly return a value. You do this with the keyword `return`.

However, there is another error in your program: you cannot compare `from<value<to`. What you need to check is that `from < value && value < to`. Basically, that both conditions are true.

The body of your function could then be simplified to: `return from < value && value < to;`

Comment: plus the code outside the function (above it in the code) is somewhat strange: `from` and `value` are assigned a value before being declared and the latter is declared twice.